# Past vs "Was/Were" for verbs in Spanish

Tags: participio

I am studying Spanish with the Michel Thomas Method. 
It says the following:

> To express the past, a Verb will end in either `-ado` or `-ido`. Before you use the past verb, you will use the appropriate prefix (e.g. `he`, `ha`, `has`, `han` or `hemos`).
>
> e.g. I have waited / he esperado
>
> In this `esperar` becomes `esperado`
>
> With `was` and `were` there are no prefixes, instead the verb ends in either -`aba` or `-ía`
>
> E.g. I was waiting / esperaba

But then it gives this example:

> He did it everyday / Lo hacía todos los días.

Shouldn't it be `ha hecho todos los días`, as there is no `was` in the sentence?

How do you generally know when to use `aba/ia` and `ado/ido`?

Comment: In Spanish there are different tenses to express slight meaning changes. You cannot learn them by studying suffixes, so you will not use the correct tenses and your sentences will not make sense. Try to see the difference in English between the Past Simple and the Past Perfect. Your original sentence is: He did it everyday. (past simple), you cannot translate it as if it were: "He has done it everyday". Because it simply doesn't make sense. Try to understand when every tense is used instead of using "tricks" to know which tense must be used. You'll learn better :)

Comment: You are interpreting the rule you read in the Michael Thomas method using converse reasoning.  It's telling you that when you see a "was/were" construct in English, you should use the imperfect in Spanish.  The converse is not necessarily the case.  When you see an imperfect in spanish, it doesn't necessarily follow that the English equivalent uses the "was/were" construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a normal, informal conversation, *He did it everyday* `Él lo hacía todos los días` is equivalent to `lo ha hecho todos los días`.

More specifically, they are different conjugations, you may check it here:
http://www.wordreference.com/conj/EsVerbs.aspx?v=hacer
`Hacía` is the **pretérito imperfecto**, and `ha hecho` is **pretérito perfecto compuesto**.

There is a subtle difference, with `hacía` there is no explicit duration, beginning or end of the action. On the other hand, `ha hecho` is an action from the past which is extended to the present time. But again, in an informal, everyday talk you can use both expressions and they will mean the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Michel Thomas Method, but I'm sure it wouldn't hurt you to read up on conjugations.  `he`, `has`, `ha`, `han`, and `hemos` are not prefixes by any stretch of the imagination.  Each are the present indicative conjugation of the verb `haber`.

`Haber` is an (nearly always) auxiliary verb (helping verb).  This is the verb that allows us to create *perfect* conjugations.  We use them in English a lot and sometimes you would wonder how we ourselves interpret their use.

[Is "haber" always a helping verb?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12590/is-haber-always-a-helping-verb/12591#12591)

> If I **had had** twelve dollars I would **have** bought it.

translates to

> Su **hubiera** tenido doce dólares lo **habría** comprado.

*The first bolded conjugation is called Past Subjunctive while the second is called Conditional*

The way haber works (as an auxiliary verb) is this

> (conjugated form of haber) + (past participle) = to have (past participle)
>
> He has eaten = Él ha comido
>
> We have finished = Hemos terminado.

Depending on which of the three kinds of verbs your verb is, you will either have -ado or -ido to express the **past participle**.

Verbs that end with an `-ar` generally switch to `-ado`
Verbs that end with an `-er` or `-ir` generally switch to `-ido`

The same goes for the other part of your question

`-Ar` verbs have an **imperfect** past tense that ends with `-aba`
`-Er` and `-Ir` verbs have an **imperfect** past tense that ends with `-ía`.

Answer (score 0):

**-aba/-ía** is for past verbs (not participle), but **-ado/-ido** holds for past participle verbs.

> I have waited

ends in **-ado** because you're using past participle. To use **esperaba** we put

> I waited

which also translates to "yo esperé," it all depends of the context so won't know whether it is "esperaba" or "esperé" if you don't know what the context is.

Now

> I was waiting

is past continuous which means **yo estaba esperando** or **yo estuve esperando**, but not **yo fui esperando** or **yo era esperando**.

For

> He did it everyday

that's **lo hacía todos los días** or **lo hizo todos los días**, but there's no **-ido** here because the past participle for **do** in spanish is **hecho**. Hence

> He has done it everyday

translates to **lo ha hecho todos los días**, which is in past participle and there's no **-ido**, so this is a particular case.